# Jboss EAP 6.1 serverlog file number continues to increase

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I have a situation where JBoss 6.1 eap server log file number continues to increase.The average number of serverlog files per day in April is 330, a maximum of 500.

In particular, since the upper limit of the number of rotations of GW serverlog per day is set to 300, it already exceeds the upper limit.
When the upper limit is exceeded, old files are getting deleted.

Please tell me how to avoid file deletion.(Do i need to increase the folder size or need to set rotation..)

As the number of users is expected to increase, the number of files is expected to continue to increase,

Comment: Some logging settings    handler.PORTALLOGGER=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler
handler.PORTALLOGGER.module=org.jboss.logmanager
handler.PORTALLOGGER.level=ALL
handler.PORTALLOGGER.properties=enabled,rotateSize,maxBackupIndex,suffix,fileName
handler.PORTALLOGGER.enabled=true
handler.PORTALLOGGER.rotateSize=31457280
handler.PORTALLOGGER.maxBackupIndex=300
handler.PORTALLOGGER.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.PORTALLOGGER.fileName=/dir1/dir2/jboss-eap-6.1/standalone/log/portal.log

Comment: ls -lrth output:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1  31M May 16 00:08 server.log.2017-05-16.109
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1  31M May 16 00:13 server.log.2017-05-16.108
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1  31M May 16 00:18 server.log.2017-05-16.107
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1  31M May 16 00:23 server.log.2017-05-16.106
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1  31M May 16 00:28 server.log.2017-05-16.105
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1  31M May 16 00:33 server.log.2017-05-16.104
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1  31M May 16 00:39 server.log.2017-05-16.103
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1  31M May 16 00:45 server.log.2017-05-16.102

Comment: df -kh
Filsyst                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_svr2-LogVol00   29G  396M   27G   2% /
tmpfs                                  32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                             248M   39M  197M  17% /boot
/dev/mapper/opt-LogVol00               15G  165M   14G   2% /opt
/dev/mapper/portal-LogVol00           193G   19G  164G  11% /portal
/dev/mapper/tmp-LogVol00              9.7G  159M  9.0G   2% /tmp
/dev/mapper/usr-LogVol00               20G  2.2G   17G  12% /usr
/dev/mapper/var-LogVol00               49G  409M   46G   1% /var